# why my iOS app is getting crashed on launching

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, appdelegate

i have built and run an iOS app and it crashed as soon as it got launched with this error in AppDelegate.swift:

> Thread 1: Exception: "*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

Following is the screenshot of code  for reference.

[image]

i am not able to identify that error is present  in which part of code so that i can debug it further by applying breakpoint.
Need help in fixing this.

adding segment of code where objects are inserted into the array for reference.

```
+ (NSArray *)relevantURLSchemes {
  NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (NSBundle *bundle in [[self class] relevantBundles]) {
    NSArray *urlTypes = [bundle objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleURLTypes"];
    for (NSDictionary *urlType in urlTypes) {
      [result addObjectsFromArray:urlType[@"CFBundleURLSchemes"]];
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: please post some code. Where you are inserting an object into array?

Comment: @Mahendra i have edited the question by putting the required code.please have a look at this

Comment: Check edited answer.

Comment: That is Objective-C, not Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to insert an null object in array.

You need to check the value before to insert it into an array.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

Make sure you have initialze it before use.

```
_arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

When you are adding an object/value in it you can check that like this.

```
NSString *strValue = nil;
if (strValue != nil) {
    [self.arr addObject:strValue];
}
```

When you are inserting in an array be sure about inserting index otherwise you will get array index out of bound error at run time.

**EDIT**

Before adding data into array you should check for the null.

```
id schemes = urlType[@"CFBundleURLSchemes"];
if (![schemes isEqual:[NSNull null]] && schemes != nil) {
   [result addObjectsFromArray: schemes];
 }
```